# Get Error storing cluster namespace secret (E0025) trying to bind service to a cluster

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, kubernetes

I am following [Tutorial: Creating Kubernetes clusters in IBM Bluemix Container Service](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_tutorials.html#cs_tutorials) but when I try to bind a service to my cluster I get:

`$ bx cs cluster-service-bind kub_cluster myns cloudant`

> FAILED
>
> Error storing cluster namespace secret (E0025)
>
> Incident ID: ebdbdd0d-5d6a-4373-8e54-b7dd84733a29

I have a worker node:

```
$ bx cs workers kub_cluster
```

will list one in State 'normal' and Status 'Ready'.

I tried with different services (messageHub and Cloudant) and different names for the namespace.  These are services I already have. Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to test this out following the same guide. I used the tone analyzer service. For testing I used the default namespace.

Are you able to see the namespace you are using when you list out available kubernetes namespaces? The option "myns" will need to be a kubernetes namespace.

```
$ kubectl get namespaces
```

This should print out the default namespace as well as other system namespaces + any namespaces you created.

Earlier in the guide a namespace is setup for the docker registry, it is possible that you are using that namespace.

Other instances of this issue appear to be related to the status of the cluster. It looks like your cluster has an available node(normal and ready), so it should be able to store the secret in an available namespace.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I needed to use 'default' as you suggest.  I had misunderstood and thought it would create one automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the specific namespace in your cluster.

You can create one by calling:

```
kubectl create namespace <your namespace>
```